# How to set object variables based on returned MySQL object

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working with a new class object I've created. The class contains 30+ variables that need to get set based on the results returned from a MySQL query.

I am currently setting variables like this:

```
    class MyClass {
        public static $id = null;
        public static $name = null;
        public static $description = null;
        public static $tags = null;
        public static $url = null;

        public function __construct( $params = null ) {

            if( $params != null ) {
                $this->id = $params->id;
                $this->name = $params->name;
                $this->description = $params->description;
                $this->tags = $params->tags;
                $this->url = $params->url;
            }
        }
    }
```

What I want to be able to do is in the construct function, loop through the $params variable and set variables within the class automatically based on the key->value pairs inside of $params.

So in pseudo-code:

```
for( size of $params ) {
    $this->($paramkeyname) = $params->($samekeyname);
}
```

Is this possible to use dynamic variable calls or can anyone suggest an easier way?

Answer (score 2):

Just use a `foreach`

```
foreach($params AS $key => $val){
    $this->$key = $val;
}
```

Just be sure that you're passing in an array

```
public function __construct(array $params = array()) {
```